# css transform: translate() % always refer to the size of bounding box?

Tags: css

I'm confused about what specifications says.
Let me clarify my understanding.

### specifications

https://www.w3.org/TR/css-transforms-1/#propdef-transform

> Percentages:  refer to the size of bounding box

https://drafts.csswg.org/css-transforms-2/#propdef-translate

> Percentages:  relative to the width of the
>     containing block (for the first value) or the height (for the second value)

### my understanding

#### css-transforms-1

1. there is  `transform` property.
   `transform` property refer to bounding box.
   so, `translate` function of `transform` property refer to bounding box.
2. there is **not** `translate` property.

#### css-transforms-2

1. there is  `transform` property.
   `transform` property refer to the size of bounding box.
   so, translate function of `transform` property refer to bounding box.
2. there is `translate` property.
   `translate` property refer to containing box.

so, I think that % of `transform: translate()` always refer to bounding box,
is this right?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your second link was just a draft to be used for discussion. As far as I know it hasn't made it into final CSS standards or implementations.

So your guess is right, percentages are related to the element's bounding box, not to the containing block.

Comment: Thanks for letting me know. I appreciate that.